# OutOfMemoryException when trying to draw tile map

Tags: c#, xna, out-of-memory

I'm trying to draw a tile map in C# and the problem I'm having is strange in my opinion.

I have this int array that is suposed to hold the x coordinate and y coordinate to draw the tiles on the screen. (The arrow with not only 0's in it is X and other one is Y)

```
int[,] level1 = { { 0, 32, 64, 96 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Here is how I use for loops to render a part of the tile into the screen and it's here I'm getting an "OutOfMemoryException" on a line that I will comment out:

```
public void DrawTest(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int x = 0;; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0;; y++)
            {
                x = level1[x, 0];
                y = level1[0, y];

                //This line bellow is where it says OutOfMemoryException
                spriteBatch.Draw(tileSheet, new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32), new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White);

                if (x >= 5 | y >= 5)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i want to call this render method i do it in the main class Render method

```
levelLoader.DrawTest(this.spriteBatch);
```

It worked perfectly before i used this DrawTest method to try drawing the tiles. But I have completely no idea why this isn't working correctly.

**UPDATE:**

```
public void DrawTest(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5 ; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 5 ; y++)
                {
                    x = level1[x, 0];
                    y = level1[0, y];
                    spriteBatch.Draw(tileSheet, new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32), new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
        public void DrawTest(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5 ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5 ; y++)
            {
                int tileXCord = level1[x, 0];
                int tileYCord = level1[0, y];
                spriteBatch.Draw(tileSheet, new Rectangle(tileXCord, tileYCord, 32, 32), new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've probably trying to batch up an unlimited number of draw calls. What are you trying to do with this weird loop?

Comment: Im trying to create a class that will draw the map of the game im making..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems in your code:

1. You have **an infinite loop** here in your code. What is the termination condition for your nested loops?
2. (important!) The `spriteBatch.Draw()` method **doesn't draw anything, it just schedules the drawing of your sprites**. This method invocation should be preceded by `spriteBatch.Begin()` (to start scheduling he drawing) and eventually you must call `spriteBatch.End()` to flush the scheduled spites to your device. You infinite loops cause the infinite scheduling of your sprite drawing until the memory is full and you are facing the out of memory exception.
3. (note!) In you condition `(x >= 5 | y >= 5)` you are using **a bitwise OR** comparison, you shouldn't do it (unless on purpose, which I don't see here and rather use boolean OR: `(x >= 5 || y >= 5)`
4. It is a very bad habit to modify loop counters within the loop itself. Not it is only errors prone, it is also difficult to understand and support your code written this way.

I would re-write your code this way

```
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            x = level1[x, 0];
            y = level1[0, y];

            //This line bellow is where it says OutOfMemoryException
            spriteBatch.Draw(tileSheet, new Rectangle(x, y, 32, 32), new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32), Color.White);
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
```

It will re-draw all your tiles on every `Draw()` event of the main gameloop (provided you are still calling this method from your `Draw()` method of your `Game` class. XNA varies the FPS rate depending upon the performance of you PC and the amount of calculation it has to be done on every frame.

Comment: Its not required to use spriteBatch.Begin() and End() i did the same think for the player class and it works perfectly.. But here its little different. If i would make an update method here it would be soo many different spriteBatch.Draw() and im planning also on havinh multiple levels and that would also make it spageti code.

Comment: No, it is required (but it should be better done only once per Draw() event), read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch_members.aspx). You can just have `Begin()` and `End()` once in your `Draw()` method, just in beginning and at the very end of your drawing and call all the Draw methods in-between.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Just to be pedantic: XNA's default setting uses a fixed frame-rate. And keeping things in the one begin/end block is only a performance advantage if consecutive draws also use the same texture ([ref](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288)).

Comment: @AndrewRussell: Doesn't XNA skip some invocations of `Draw()` events if the `Update()` takes too long? And I agree about SpriteBatch, I just simplified its role in my answer.

Comment: Yes that's true. I suppose you could say that dropping frames like this is varying the FPS. However XNA does include a true variable frame-rate mode - it's just not the default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck in an infinite loop. You need to exit somehow to avoid the out of memory exception.

Comment: How would i still make the tiles to be drawn?